# How to solve: WARNING : deprecated key derivation used. Using -iter or -pbkdf2 would be better

Tags: encryption, openssl

I am using OpenSSL version 1.1.1b (26 Feb 2019) to encrypt/decrypt files.

Everything is working fine but I am getting a Warning I do not understand.

```
openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -a -pass pass:$pwd -in $file

*** WARNING : deprecated key derivation used.
Using -iter or -pbkdf2 would be better.
```

Can anyone explain to me what is it about and how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file was probably encrypted by LibreSSL (using Mac?) and you are decrypting it with OpenSSL (Linux).

You don't face this problem if you encrypt and decrypt using LibreSSL for both.

Comment: Indeed I finally solved using OpenSSL for both. LibreSSL was the default on Mac even though the command is still `openssl`. Still puzzled though, they should apply the same aes-256 algo.

Comment: How did you change the default on the mac to not use LibreSSL?

Comment: @JosephAstrahan: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62195898/openssl-still-pointing-to-libressl-2-8-3

Answer (score 1):

The warning is happening due to improvements since version 1.1.0 of OpenSSL, (and was already explained a few months before in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/507131/openssl-1-1-1b-warning-using-iter-or-pbkdf2-would-be-better-while-decrypting))